# Having trouble updating GitHub pages with React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I have a deployed active react app through GitHub pages and I'm looking to update it with newer code, i.e. color changes, update text, etc. The code has already been pushed to my GitHub repo, on my main branch but it's not updating the live GitHub page. I'm obviously missing something but couldn't find anything reading documentation or other stackoverflow questions. Can anyone help? Also I've seen a lot of people posting their package.json so here's mine

Edit: I already have the github pages live with prior code, but pushing the newer code to live is what I need help with.

```
{
    "name": "react-portfolio",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": "true",
    "homepage": "N/A",
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "predeploy": "npm run build"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how React apps are published to GitHub Pages. I'd expect that you'd deploy a production build. Is that what's happening here, or is there an auto-build mechanism at play which processes your source code?

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but other than the build script in my package.json I was unable to find anything that built the app

Comment: Try viewing this documentation: https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/#:~:text=The%20simplicity%20of%20deploying%20a,own%20custom%20domain%20or%20subdomain.

Comment: Check how you've set up your GitHub Pages configuration, specifically which branch is configured to be the pages branch. Is it `main` or is it `gh-pages` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to consider to add `gh-pages-deploy` in your script list.

Because of it will enable you to deploy straight to your github pages with one simple command.

But first, you neet to do `npm install gh-pages-deploy -g` to install the package globally in your environtment.

Here was the docs for [gh-pages-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages-deploy).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GH-pages-deploy** to deploy your project to GitHub Pages

```
# install it from npm and symlink it into your PATH
npm install gh-pages-deploy -g

# now run it!
gh-pages-deploy
```

Or you can do several options to be able to run **GH-pages-deploy** by looking at the following [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages-deploy)